# Redeploying (Updating) Rails App w/ Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, postgresql, passenger

I have what I hope is a simple question.  I'm pretty new to rails/web apps, so I apologize for any obvious lack of knowledge demonstrated in asking this question.

Essentially, I've been updating/maintaining an existing Rails app that I didn't develop/deploy.  Up to this point, all the changes I've made are so minor that I felt comfortable doing them live (undesirable, I know), but I've recently had to make some changes that involved installing some new gems and updating the database.  To do so, I pulled the app/db from the production server, recreated the production environment, and made all necessary changes locally.  Put simply, my question is: what is the safest/easiest way to update the app/bundle/db on the production server?

I know there are myriad tutorials regarding deployment with Passenger, but I haven't been able to find anything that specifically references updating an app that's already in production.  Is there a distinction between initial deployment and redeploying an updated app?

Tech stack is Ruby 1.9.3, Phusion Passenger on Apache, and PostgreSQL 9.1.3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* simply upload the code, run `bundle install` then `bundle exec rake db:migrate` and call it a day, but the standard procedure would be to use something like [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano), for which myriad tutorials and guides are available on deploying Rails apps.